# No Module named "pynput"

Tags: python, pynput

My code

```
import random
import time
import pynput

import pynput.keyboard as kb
import pynput.mouse as ms

mouse    = ms.Controller()
keyboard = kb.Controller()
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\visual studio code\notepadtest.py", line 1, in <module>
   from pynput import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'
```

When i try to pip3 install it shows that it is already installed

how do i fix this?

Comment: Are you using any virtual environment or something?

Comment: What do you get when you run ```pip show pynput``` ?

Comment: this is what pip show pynput gives me

Name: pynput
Version: 1.7.3
Summary: Monitor and control user input devices
Home-page: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput
Author: Moses Palmér
Author-email: moses.palmer@gmail.com
License: 
Location: c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.39\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
Requires: six
Required-by:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every module you download saves in site_package folder of python's folder, (dir:Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages).First open the folder where your python is installed (default directory is shown in the Image_[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0yUW.jpg)),then go to site_packages folder and copy your module(i-e '**pynput**') from there.

There is also a site_pakages folder in project you make,like I noramaly use pycharm,as you can see in Image_[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Esu.jpg), I made a project with a name 'Hangman Game' and pycharm automatically made a site_pakages folder inside venu folder.You just have to paste your module (i-e '**pynput**') there, run your program again and you will not get any error after that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent so long trying to solve this